# Rails: How filter all objects with specific parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a shorter way to write this ?

```
Job.all(:conditions => "job_source_id=1")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little shorter and more readable:

```
Job.where :job_source_id => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the  Dynamic Finders

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders

```
Job.find_by_source_id(1)
```

Comment: It returns only the first job found.

Comment: @Misha - You can also do `Job.find_all_by_source_id(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to use scopes for this kind of thing like so:

```
# in the model
scope :from_sales, :conditions => { :job_source_id => 1 }
```

Then, from anywhere, I can just call:

```
Job.from_sales.all
```

This lets me express myself in my problem domain instead of sql.